# How to send myself alert if API fails?

Tags: python-3.x, response, api-design

I am making API calls too a website, using the 'response' library in python.

How do I send myself an alert (in any form, email, text, etc) if I get a response object other than 200?

Is there a python library that will handle this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told to check out the smtplib